# If $k\geq3$ then $\binom{\lfloor2^{k/2}\rfloor}{k}2^{1-\binom{k}{2}}<1$.

Tags: number-theory, inequality, binomial-coefficients, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can we show that
$\binom{\lfloor2^{k/2}\rfloor}{k}2^{1-\binom{k}{2}}<1$ when $k\geq 3$? I tried using Stirling approximation but it turned out to be a mess, do you see a smarter proof?

More generally, this inequality arises when we want to decide for which natural numbers $n$ $$\binom{n}{k}2^{1-\binom{k}{2}}<1$$ how might one even think of something like $n=\lfloor2^{k/2}\rfloor$ and $k\geq 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the upper bound ${n \choose k}\leq (en/k)^k$. Applying this here with $n=\lfloor 2^{k/2}\rfloor$ gives
\begin{equation}
{\lfloor 2^{k/2}\rfloor \choose k}2^{1-{k \choose 2}}\leq 2\cdot \frac{e^k}{k^k} \cdot 2^{(k^2/2)-k(k-1)/2}=2\left(\frac{e\sqrt{2}}{k}\right)^k.
\end{equation}
This is less that $1$ for $k\geq 5$. For $k=3,4$, one can check your inequality holds by hand pretty directly.

As for how you see this quantity, the above inequality suggests you should take $n$ such that $n^k\approx 2^{k(k-1)/2}$, which suggests taking $n\approx 2^{k/2}$.

Comment: $\binom nk \le (\frac{en}{k})^k$ is overkill; just with $\binom nk \le \frac{n^k}{k!}$ and $\lfloor k/2 \rfloor \le k/2$ this inequality reduces to $2^{k/2+1} < k!$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Oof, that's much cleaner--I typically default to the weaker bound and didn't even think to check the sharper one directly works...